# How to calculate average level on certain days and times in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a data frame like so

| Date_Time | Level |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-08-08 23:55:01 | 239.0 |
| 2017-08-08 23:50:01 | 242.0 |
| 2017-08-08 23:45:01 | 246.0 |
| 2017-08-08 23:40:01 | 250.0 |
| 2017-08-08 23:35:01 | 254.0 |
| ... | ... |
| 2017-07-26 00:23:57 | 72.0 |
| 2017-07-26 00:18:57 | 67.0 |
| 2017-07-26 00:13:57 | 64.0 |
| 2017-07-26 00:08:57 | 64.0 |
| 2017-07-26 00:03:57 | 65.0 |

I want to calculate the average level on every day, during the waking hours and overnight hours

| Date | Time | AvgLevel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017-08-08 | 00:00:00 - 06:00:00 | 178 |
| 2017-08-08 | 06:00:01 - 23:59:99 | 190 |
| 2017-09-08 | 00:00:00 - 06:00:00 | 174 |
| 2017-09-08 | 06:00:01 - 23:59:99 | 200 |

I've already tried splitting into separate tables and using for loops however that uses too much memory and takes too much time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` to differentiate between waking hours and overnight hours

Creating sample data

```
data = {
    'Date_Time': [
        '2017-08-08 00:00:00', '2017-08-08 23:50:01', '2017-08-08 06:45:01',
        '2017-08-08 06:00:00', '2017-08-08 00:35:01',
        '2017-07-26 00:23:57', '2017-07-26 00:18:57', '2017-07-26 07:13:57',
        '2017-07-26 00:08:57', '2017-07-26 07:03:57'
    ],
    'Level': [239.0, 242.0, 246.0, 250.0, 254.0, 72.0, 67.0, 64.0, 64.0, 65.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Date_Time', 'Level'])
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])
df = df.set_index('Date_Time')
print(df)

                     Level
Date_Time                 
2017-08-08 00:00:00  239.0
2017-08-08 23:50:01  242.0
2017-08-08 06:45:01  246.0
2017-08-08 06:00:00  250.0
2017-08-08 00:35:01  254.0
2017-07-26 00:23:57   72.0
2017-07-26 00:18:57   67.0
2017-07-26 07:13:57   64.0
2017-07-26 00:08:57   64.0
2017-07-26 07:03:57   65.0
```

Creating a mask of waking hours and overnight hours

```
mask = (df.index.time >= pd.to_datetime('00:00:00').time()) & (df.index.time <= pd.to_datetime('06:00:00').time())
df['Period'] = np.where(mask, '00:00:00 - 06:00:00', '06:00:01 - 23:59:59')
df

                     Level               Period
Date_Time                                      
2017-08-08 00:00:00  239.0  00:00:00 - 06:00:00
2017-08-08 23:50:01  242.0  06:00:01 - 23:59:59
2017-08-08 06:45:01  246.0  06:00:01 - 23:59:59
2017-08-08 06:00:00  250.0  00:00:00 - 06:00:00
2017-08-08 00:35:01  254.0  00:00:00 - 06:00:00
2017-07-26 00:23:57   72.0  00:00:00 - 06:00:00
2017-07-26 00:18:57   67.0  00:00:00 - 06:00:00
2017-07-26 07:13:57   64.0  06:00:01 - 23:59:59
2017-07-26 00:08:57   64.0  00:00:00 - 06:00:00
2017-07-26 07:03:57   65.0  06:00:01 - 23:59:59
```

Groupby the `Date_Time` and `Period` column and calculate average `Level`

```
result = df.groupby([df.index.date, 'Period'])['Level'].mean().reset_index()
result.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'AvgLevel']
result

         Date                 Time    AvgLevel
0  2017-07-26  00:00:00 - 06:00:00   67.666667
1  2017-07-26  06:00:01 - 23:59:59   64.500000
2  2017-08-08  00:00:00 - 06:00:00  247.666667
3  2017-08-08  06:00:01 - 23:59:59  244.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=";")
print(df)
df["Date_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date_Time"])

df["Date"] = df["Date_Time"].dt.date
df["Time"] = df["Date_Time"].dt.time

df["Time_Period"] = "Overnight"
df.loc[(df["Time"] >= pd.to_datetime("06:00:00").time()) & (df["Time"] <= pd.to_datetime("23:59:59").time()), "Time_Period"] = "Waking"

grouped = df.groupby(["Date", "Time_Period"])["Level"].mean().reset_index()

grouped = grouped.rename(columns={"Date": "Date", "Time_Period": "Time", "Level": "AvgLevel"})

grouped["Time"] = grouped["Time"].map({
    "Waking": "06:00:01 - 23:59:99",
    "Overnight": "00:00:00 - 06:00:00"
})

print(grouped)
```

Basically, you group entries by times that are nightly and daily:

This results in (I assume here that your expected outcome you print is for the entire dataframe):

```
         Date                 Time  AvgLevel
0  2017-07-26  00:00:00 - 06:00:00      66.4
1  2017-08-08  06:00:01 - 23:59:99     246.2
```

Answer (score 0):

by using Pandas `freq` option, mean, sum etc. can be calculated for an equal portion of time i.e. `freq='H'` for hourly calculation, `freq='12H'` for 12 hourly calculation, `freq='D'` for daily calculation and `freq='BH'` for business hoursly calculations.
Example is below:

```
avg_12_hours = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='12H', key='Date_Time'))['Level'].mean()
```

Since, you are asking for a calculation period which is not equally splitted so, you need to do some custom calculations